# Git works fine locally, but when accessing machine remotely Git asks for password

Tags: git, ssh, remote-server

I have two machines, a Macbook Pro and an iMac. When I'm traveling, I use my laptop to dev. When I'm at home I prefer to use the iMac for dev because of the big screen, and use my laptop as a server.

The problem arises when I SSH into the laptop and try to run git commands from the iMac. Git asks for my password on every command that interacts with remotes.

Both computers are setup with the same .gitconfig. I am using public keys for authentication with the laptop.

This is annoying. I know there are workarounds, but how do I fix this in particular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using "public keys for authentication". Therefore you need your private key to authenticate to the server. If no private key is available, ssh will fall back to password authentication and ask for the password.

Did you store your private key on the Macbook or the iMac?

Assuming you have a copy on the Macbook and some ssh-agent running, `ssh-add -L` should print the correct public key.

In this case you can use `ssh -A` to forward the agent to your Macbook, where it can use that key for authentication.